# Button stays pressed in mobile view

Tags: html, css

This button in desktop view works fine, but in mobile view the button stays pressed down.

```css
:root {
  --green: #4285f4;
  --black: rgba(9, 13, 25, 0.752);
  --box-shadow: .4rem .4rem 1rem #ccc, -.4rem -.4rem 1rem #fff;
  --box-shadow-inset: .4rem .4rem 1rem #ccc inset, -.4rem -.4rem 1rem #fff inset;
}

#theme-toggler {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--black);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

#theme-toggler:hover {
  color: var(--green);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-inset);
}
```

```html
<div id="theme-toggler" class="fas fa-moon"></div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a5ea1b4e1c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ismailummer/pen/BaxdqMg)

Comment: On mobile browsers typically apply hover effects to elements with focus, the button probably still has focus after tapping - this is intentional.

Comment: A `<div>` is not a `<button>`  Think about using semantic valid HTML for your site. Other than that: Mobile devices don't know hover, they apply hover styles when an element is focused (it will be focused after clicking it)

Comment: @cloned changes added in codepen still problem persist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to prevent hover on mobile is to always put hover on media query **bigger than mobile screen**. so it only works if `viewport` `width` is more than mobile query.

and if you want the style to happen only when clicking the button on mobile, then just add `active` out of the query or in mobile query.

below `hover` will work only if `viewport` `width` is more than `600px`.

```css
:root {
  --green: #4285f4;
  --black: rgba(9, 13, 25, 0.752);
  --box-shadow: .4rem .4rem 1rem #ccc, -.4rem -.4rem 1rem #fff;
  --box-shadow-inset: .4rem .4rem 1rem #ccc inset, -.4rem -.4rem 1rem #fff inset;
}

#theme-toggler {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1.5rem;
  right: 2rem;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--black);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  #theme-toggler:hover {
    color: var(--green);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-inset);
  }
}

  #theme-toggler:active {
      color: var(--green);
      box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-inset);
    }
```

```html
<div id="theme-toggler" class="fas fa-moon"></div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a5ea1b4e1c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```